# Any positive integer can be written as $2^{\sum_{k=1}^N n_k+m_k}+\sum_{i=1}^{N} 2^{\left(\sum_{k=i}^N n_k+m_{k+1}\right)}\left(2^{m_i}-1\right)$

Tags: number-theory, induction, natural-numbers

I want to prove this theorem:

**Theorem:** For every natural number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, there exist natural numbers (they can be $0$): $\{n_1,...,n_N\} $ and $\{m_1,...,m_N\}$ such that:

$$n=2^{(n_1+...+n_N)+(m_1+...+m_N)}+\sum_{i=1}^{N} 2^{(n_{i}+...+n_N)+(m_{i+1}+...+m_N)}\big(2^{m_i}-1\big)$$

**For example:**

For $n=6$, choose $n_1=1=m_1$. Then:
$$6=2^{n_1+m_1}+2^{n_1+0} (2^m_1-1)=2^2+2(2-1)=4+2=6$$

For $n=2$, choose $n_1=1, m_1=0$.
$$2=2^{n_1+m_1}+2^{n_1+0}(2^m_1-1)=2^1+2^1(1-1)=2$$

¿How can I proof this by induction? Any ideas?

Comment: What is a null number?

Comment: $0$ @JoshuaTilley

Comment: is $N$ a fixed positive integer?

Comment: @Marco yes, $N$ can be $1,2,3,...$

Comment: @tomascatuxo but $N$ has to be always the same for all $n$ or it can change?

Comment: @Marco It can change. For example for $n=23$, $N=4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let call
$$
f(N)=2^{(n_1+...+n_N)+(m_1+...+m_N)}+\sum_{i=1}^{N} 2^{(n_{i}+...+n_N)+(m_{i+1}+...+m_N)}\big(2^{m_i}-1\big)
$$
we have
$$
f(N)=2^{n_N+m_N} \left(2^{(n_1+...+n_{N-1})+(m_1+...+m_{N-1})}+\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} 2^{(n_{i}+...+n_{N-1})+(m_{i+1}+...+m_{N-1})}\big(2^{m_i}-1\big)\right)+ 2^{n_N}(2^{m_N}-1)
$$
so
$$
f(N)=2^{n_N+m_N} f(N-1) + 2^{n_N}(2^{m_N}-1)
$$
Now assume that a number $n=f(N-1)$ for some coefficients $(n_1,\cdots n_{N-1})$,$(m_1,\cdots m_{N-1})$ than $2n=f(N)$ with coefficients
$$
(n_1,\cdots n_{N-1},1),(m_1,\cdots m_{N-1},0)
$$
and $2n+1=f(N)$ with coefficients
$$
(n_1,\cdots n_{N-1},0),(m_1,\cdots m_{N-1},1)
$$
so the theorem is true by [prefix induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Prefix_induction) (see also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3236719/what-is-a-good-example-of-prefix-induction) question)

This also prove that you can choose $n_i, m_i \in \{0,1\}$